# Parents of Narada muni?

Tags: narada

Who are the parents of Narada?

I want to know the name of Narada muni's father and mother.

Comment: In Shreemad Bhagvat purana we find mentioning by Narada that ,in previous  birth in previous kalpa he was a servant boy (Dasi-putra) of a Brahmana.And only child.But no mentioning of name of his mother.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Devarshi Narada was created by Lord Brahma alone. So,he is only Lord Brahma's progeny.**

I am using the book ["Essence of Narada Charitra"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/ESSENCE-OF-NARADA-CHARITRA.pdf) as my reference here:

**Creation of Brahma:**

> Later on Brahma continued his Srishti from his ‘Prishta’ (rear side)  Adharma and Alakshmi; from his ‘nabhi’ (navel) Vishwakarma the Shilpa Guru, from his ‘Balaparakrama’or prowess Eight Vaus; Manasa Putras (mind-born sons) Sanaka, Sanandana, Sanatana, Sanatkumaras; Swayambhu Manu and his wife Shatarupa the Administrator of the Universe.......from Brahma’s shadow came out kardama, Panchashikha from his navel, from chest came out  Odhu, **from Brahma’s throat came Narada**, shoulder Marichi, from neck  Apaantaratama, from tongue Vasishtha, from lips Pracheta, from left belly came out Hamsa (Swan) and Yati from the right belly.

Comment: why dont you provide a puranic account for this maybe vishnu purana or skanda purana.

Comment: @Yogi The book i quoted is based on Puranas only..The book is hosted by the Kamakoti.org..