# Who is narada muni and who is father and mother of narada muni ?

Tags: narada

Who is Narada muni and who is father and mother of Narada muni? How did he become a devotee of Sreeman Narayana.

Comment: The question "Who is naradha muni and who is the father and mother of naradha muni" is already present . How did he became a devotee of Sreeman Narayana can be answered from Puranas.So your question is partially duplicate. it's advisable to omit  the duplicate part from your question .

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: I searched in the SO but the spell of Naradhar instead of Narada will be confused. Thanks.

Comment: At some places over the internet Narada Muni was called as Naradhar , but both the names are same. Only pronunciation  difference is there. Generally in south India people include "h" in spellings. May be the confusion is because of that.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [Parents of Narada muni?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16544/5212)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How   Narada became Devotee of Narayana  is told by he himself to Veda-Vyasa  in The Skanda one Chapters [**Five**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/5) and [**Six**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/6) of **Srimad Bhagavatam** - These chapters are about Past life of Narada Muni and his brief life story , like how he became Parshada  of Lord Vishnu by his devotion .

Here is the brief life story of Narada Muni.

He was the son of the most insignificant parentage. He was not properly educated. Still, because his complete energy was engaged in the service of the Lord, he became an immortal sage.

He  was not naughty in his childhood ( 5 years of age ) , during that he was engaged in the service of some Brahmanas who were following the principles of Vedanta and  who were conducting four month vrata. Even though he was a boy he  was self-controlled and had no attachment for sports. He used to eat the remaining food from their dishes only from their permission . Thus he became purified in heart, and at that time the very nature of the transcendentalist became attractive to him. Those Brahmanas told various stories of Supreme Lord to Narada ,and thus his devotion increased. He  was strictly following them with body and mind. At the time of their departure they instructed Narada about   most confidential subject which is instructed by the Supreme Lord Himself. And thus he gained the knowledge.

> अहं पुरातीतभवेsभवं मुने दास्यास्तु कस्याश्चन वेदवादिनाम् ।
>  
>   निरूपितो बालक एव योगिनां शुश्रूषणे प्रावृषि निर्विवक्षताम् ॥[**SB
>   1.5.23**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/5/23)॥
>
> O Muni, in the last millennium I was born as the son of a certain
>   maidservant engaged in the service of brahmanas who were following the
>   principles of Vedanta. When they were living together during the four
>   months of the rainy season, I was engaged in their personal service.
>
> ---
>
> उच्छिष्टलॆपाननुमॊदितॊ द्विजै: सकृत्स्म भुञ्जे तदपास्तकिल्बिष: ।
>  
>   एवं प्रवृत्तस्य विशुद्धचेतस- स्तद्धर्म एवात्मरुचि: प्रजायते ॥ [**SB
>   1.5.25**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/5/25) ॥
>
> Once only, by their permission, I took the remnants of their food, and
>   by so doing all my sins were at once eradicated. Thus being engaged, I
>   became purified in heart, and at that time the very nature of the
>   transcendentalist became attractive to me.
>
> ---
>
> ज्ञानं गुह्यतमं यत्तत् साक्षात्भगवतोदितम् । 
>  अन्ववोचन् गमिष्यन्त:
>   कृपया दीनवत्सला: ॥ [**SB 1.5.30**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/5/30)   ॥
>
> As they were leaving, those bhakti-vedantas, who are very kind to
>   poor-hearted souls, instructed me in that most confidential subject
>   which is instructed by the Personality of Godhead Himself.

After that in an unfortunate incidance Narad Munis mother died because of snake bite in the dark of the night. Narad Muni in grief of his mothers death started walking towards north. In his journey he  passed through many flourishing metropolises, towns, villages, animal farms, mines, agricultural lands, valleys, flower gardens, nursery gardens and natural forests.While  traveling, once he  felt tired, both bodily and mentally, and  was both thirsty and hungry. So he took a bath in a river lake and also drank water.

Then  under the shadow of a banyan tree in an uninhabited forest he began to meditate upon the Supersoul situated within, using his intelligence, as he  had learned from liberated souls. As he  began to meditate upon the lotus feet of the Supreme Lord with his mind transformed in transcendental love, tears rolled down through his  eyes, and Supreme Lord  appeared on the lotus of his heart. By seeing Narada in full devotional service the Supreme Lord Said to him " narada you can not see me in this life . But you now because of short service of sages and by your  devotion will leave this material body and will became my "Parshada" (attendent ) , your memory will remain as it is. And by thus Narada Mui became pure from heart his material attachment completely ended. And after some time  he left his material body and gained the divine body of lord's attendant.

He then  began chanting the holy name and fame of the Lord by repeated recitation, ignoring all the formalities of the material world. At the end of the Kalpa when Lord Narayana decided to sleep , Lord Brahma wished to sleep in his heart and started to collect whole universe , Narada through his breath entered into body  Of lord Brahma. 
After the end of  thousand Chatur-Yugas and When lord Brahma `awaked and decided to start creation , Narada and Marichi rishi etc. again came out from the Brahma's body.

> एकदा निर्गतां गेहाद्दुहन्तीं निशि गां पथि ।
>  सर्पोऽदशत्पदा स्पृष्टः
>   कृपणां कालचोदितः ॥ [**SB 1.6.9**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/6/9) ॥
>
> Once upon a time, my poor mother, when going out one night to milk a
>   cow, was bitten on the leg by a serpent, influenced by supreme time.
>
> ---
>
> तस्मिन्निर्मनुजेऽरण्ये पिप्पलोपस्थ आश्रितः ।
>   आत्मनात्मानमात्मस्थं यथाश्रुतमचिन्तयम् ॥SB 1.6.15॥
>   ध्यायतश्चरणाम्भोजं भावनिर्जितचेतसा ।
>  औत्कण्ठ्याश्रुकलाक्षस्य
>   हृद्यासीन्मे शनैर्हरिः ॥ [**SB 1.6.15**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/6/16)॥
>
> After that, under the shadow of a banyan tree in an uninhabited forest
>   I began to meditate upon the Supersoul situated within, using my
>   intelligence, as I had learned from liberated souls.As soon as I began
>   to meditate upon the lotus feet of the Personality of Godhead with my
>   mind transformed in transcendental love, tears rolled down my eyes,
>   and without delay the Personality of Godhead, Sri Krsna, appeared on
>   the lotus of my heart.
>
> ---
>
> सकृद्यद्दर्शितं रूपमेतत्कामाय तेऽनघ ।
>  मत्कामः शनकैः साधु
>   सर्वान्मुञ्चति हृच्छयान् ॥ [**SB 1.6.22**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/6/22)॥
>
> O virtuous one, you have only once seen My person, and this is just to
>   increase your desire for Me, because the more you hanker for Me, the
>   more you will be freed from all material desires.
>
> ---
>
> प्रयुज्यमाने
>   मयि तां शुद्धां भागवतीं तनुम् । 
> आरब्धकर्मनिर्वाणो न्यपतत्पाञ्चभौतिकः ॥
>   [**SB 1.6.28**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/6/28)॥
>
> Having been awarded a transcendental body befitting an associate of
>   the Personality of Godhead, I quit the body made of five material
>   elements, and thus all acquired fruitive results of work [karma]
>   stopped.
>
> ---
>
> कल्पान्त इदमादाय शयानेऽम्भस्युदन्वतः । शिशयिषोरनुप्राणं
>   विविशेऽन्तरहं विभोः ॥SB 1.6.29॥ सहस्रयुगपर्यन्ते उत्थायेदं सिसृक्षतः ।
>   मरीचिमिश्रा ऋषयः प्राणेभ्योऽहं च जज्ञिरे ॥ [**SB 1.6.30**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/6/30)॥
>
> At the end of the millennium, when the Personality of Godhead, Lord
>   Narayana, lay down within the water of devastation, Brahma began to
>   enter into Him along with all creative elements, and I also entered
>   through His breathing. After 4,300,000,000 solar years, when Brahma
>   awoke to create again by the will of the Lord, all the rsis like
>   Marici, Aṅgira, Atri and so on were created from the transcendental
>   body of the Lord, and I also appeared along with them.

---

So Narada Muni became supreme devotee of Narayana through his pure devotional service towards him and serving the sages honestly , who imparted him the secreat knowledge which was told by lord himeself. Thus by the blessing of the sages he became aware of the knowledge , through which one can achieve lord. Then Narayana Himself  endowed him  first with the transcendental knowledge of the Lord as inculcated in the confidential parts of the Vedas, then with the spiritual opulences, and then with His intimate loving service.

**Narada Became Devotee Of Narayana By his true devotion and by   grace of the lord himself .**

Comment: Great and awesome answer with detailed reference.